# Python 'requests' module causing ConnectionError

Tags: python, python-requests, cherrypy

I have a web app which used to work perfectly fine on local until I put it on a server where I had to install the necessary packages (inclunding Python's 'requests') locally, since I don't have the root access. 
After I run the app on server, it starts by working fine, and certain kinds of queries return correct output. Though when it comes to queries which need to use certain functions from my wsgi including the use of the 'requests' module, an error is yielded:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usrname/SEMWEB/simple/app.py", line 206, in _app
    req = get(url, verify=False)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.5.1-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 65, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.5.1-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.5.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.5.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.5.1-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))
```

I use Cherrypy which I call as follows in my wsgi file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    wsgi_app = RdfDemoApp("http://localhost:3030/ds/query")

    try:
        server = CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0',8000), wsgi_app)
        server.start()
```

Comment: Your `request.get()` call simply fails; the server name you are trying to connect to doesn't resolve.

Comment: As @MartijnPieters said, you are `get`ting `http://a.server.that.does.not.exist/`; the error might be in your `app.py` near line `206`; you'd want to print the value of `url` in there to verify it is a valid url.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: or the local DNS configuration is incomplete / broken / deliberately filtering.

Comment: Or the `localhost` is missing from `/etc/hosts`, or practically anything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the url is valid, have just checked

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, in /etc/hosts there is a line "127.0.0.1 localhost", should be ok then?

Comment: yeah, then, then the next question is, if you take the hostname from the url and try to resolve it on the server, say `host the.host.name`, does it even work there?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this gave the error `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached` . I also just tried in Python requests.get('url_from_line_206') and it resulted in the exact same ConnectionError.

Comment: so, the `/etc/resolv.conf` is broken (if this is a linux server); the DNS setup is broken; generally you'd have to contact the administrator of the box... or actually, you could try if say `google.com` resolves correctly?

Comment: @user3241376: yet it is *not resolving* when you are running the code on the server.  That may be a server configuration issue.

Comment: Also: this `url` from the line 206 refers to the page hosted on the same server but created by another user. Can it be that I should name it differently from the way it is shown in a normal browser?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Just tried `host google.com`  also got the "connection time out" error

Comment: so, DNS setup is broken on the server, not much we can do except you could do DNS requests yourself; easier to contact the administrator of the box.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thnx a lot! I will contact the administrator.

Comment: @user3241376 : Was your issue resolved ? If yes, could you please include it as an answer ?